# create sql hierarchyid siblings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a database table to which I have just added a hierarchy column. The only other relevant column is the ID column (primary key). The entry with ID = 1 is my root (set to HierarchyID::GetRoot()). I can create a child in the hierarchy just fine, however I cannot seem to figure out a way to iterate through my existing data to make all of the remaining entries children of the root. All of my attempts end up with all of the other rows having the same Hierarchy value.

IE - the hierarchy should look like this:

```
ID | Hierarchy
-------------
1  | /
2  | /1
3  | /2
etc
```

My attempts all look like

```
ID | Hierarchy
-------------
1  | /
2  | /1
3  | /1
etc
```

Is there some form of simple update statement or cursor loop I can use to populate my table?
Even better is there a way to populate it so that the Hierarchy.ToString() makes the # in /# equal to the ID? (this would be nice but far from needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a string with `ID` and use it as a parameter to [hierarchyid::Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677201.aspx)

```
update T
set Hierarchy = case when ID = 1 
                  then hierarchyid::GetRoot() 
                  else hierarchyid::Parse('/'+cast(ID as varchar(10))+'/') 
                end
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3c0f/3)